# How to inject controller in karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

```
describe("App defination", function() {
beforeEach(module('app'));
  var MainCtrl, scope;

describe("ModuleTwo", function() {

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope){
           scope= $rootScope.$new();
           MainCtrl =$controller('TestCtrl',{ $scope: scope});
  }));
         it("check scope", function() {
                expect(scope).toBeDefined();
         });
  });


});
```

I am unable to access scope in that block. It gives me error like "Expected undefined to defined". When I rename TestCtrl to anystring it doesnt affect jasmine at all. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Check if your module is calles `app` or `App`.

```js
angular.module('App', []);

angular.module('App').controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
});

describe("App", function() {
  beforeEach(module('App'));
  
  var MainCtrl, scope;
  describe("TestCtrl", function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
       scope = $rootScope.$new();
       MainCtrl = $controller('TestCtrl', { $scope: scope });
    }));
    it("should have a scope", function() {
      expect(scope).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.5.2/boot.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do:

1) Add a reference to the controller and to both angular / angular-mock in `karma.conf.js` :

```
 files: [
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',                             // angular
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',                 // angular-mocks
      './app/views/js/controllers/sugestionController.js',  // <---- your controller name
      './test/**/*.js'
    ],
```

2) In your test file you must inject your module and your controller:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('socialMeal'));  //<---- module injection

var $controller;
var sugestionController;

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_){ //<---- controller injection
    $controller = _$controller_;
    sugestionController = $controller('SugestionController', {});
}));
```

Comment: that won't work because the controller may have dependencies